# Use Java and RegEx to convert casing in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, uppercase, lowercase

Problem: Turn

```
"My Testtext TARGETSTRING My Testtext"
```

into

```
"My Testtext targetstring My Testtext"
```

Perl supports the "\L"-operation which can be used in the replacement-string.

The Pattern-Class does not support this operation:

> Perl constructs not supported by this class:
>   [...] 
>   The preprocessing operations \l \u, \L, and \U.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: I don't get this. What's wrong with `"my testtext TARGETSTRING my testtext".toLowerCase();` ?

Comment: Sorry, the example was bad. toLowerCase does not work for "My Testtext TARGETSTRING My Testtext"

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can't do this in Java regex. You'd have to manually post-process using [`String.toUpperCase()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) and [`toLowerCase()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) instead.

Here's an example of how you use regex to find and capitalize words of length at least 3 in a sentence

```
    String text = "no way oh my god it cannot be";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w{3,}\\b").matcher(text);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int last = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        sb.append(text.substring(last, m.start()));
        sb.append(m.group(0).toUpperCase());
        last = m.end();
    }
    sb.append(text.substring(last));

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    // prints "no WAY oh my GOD it CANNOT be"
```

---

#### Note on `appendReplacement` and `appendTail`

Note that the above solution uses `substring` and manages a `tail` index, etc. In fact, you can go without these if you use [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and `appendTail`.

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().toUpperCase());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
```

Note how `sb` is now a [`StringBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead of [`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Until `Matcher` provides `StringBuilder` overloads, you're stuck with the slower `StringBuffer` if you want to use these methods.

It's up to you whether the trade-off in less efficiency for higher readability is worth it or not.

#### See also

- [`StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

Comment: Since Java 9, [Matcher.appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuilder-java.lang.String-) has an overload for [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 16):

## Java9+

From Java 9+ you can use [**Matcher::replaceAll**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) where you can use a `Function<MatchResult, String>` for example we use the example of [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770977/5558072) :

```
String text = "this is just a test which upper all short words";
String regex = "\\b\\w{0,3}\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
String result = matcher.replaceAll(matche -> matche.group().toUpperCase());

System.out.println(result);
```

Or Just :

```
String result = Pattern.compile(regex)
        .matcher(text)
        .replaceAll(matche -> matche.group().toUpperCase());
```

**Output**

```
this IS just A test which upper ALL short words
     ^^      ^                  ^^^
```

Answer (score 14):

To do this on regexp level you have to use `\U` to switch on uppercase mode and `\E` to switch it off. Here is an example how to use this feature in IntelliJ IDEA `find-and-replace` dialog which transforms set of class fields to JUnit assertions (at IDE tooltip is a result of `find-and-replace` transformation):

[image]

Comment: This is IntelliJ-specific though, plain Java regular expressions doesn't support this.

Comment: There's also `\L` for lower case mode (which is also ended with `\E`). Of course this is IntelliJ-specific too.

Comment: @ddekany technically, you are right: JDK lib doesn't support it (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html  see 'Comparison to Perl 5') but I guess IntelliJ IDEA uses some standalone regexp lib.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [regexp capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (if you really need to use regex, that is, meaning if "`TARGETSTRING`" is complex enough and "regular" enough to justify being detected by a regex).
You would then apply `toLowerCase()` to the group #1.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TargetToLowerCase {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder(
            "my testtext TARGETSTRING my testtext");
    System.out.println(sb);
    String regex= "TARGETSTRING ";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex); // Create the pattern.
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(sb); // Create the matcher.
    while (matcher.find()) {
      String buf= sb.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()).toLowerCase();
      sb.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), buf);
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be psuedo-code?  The `"$1".toLowerCase()` obviously evaluates first, so replaceAll just sees `"$1"`, which means it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Matthew: right, the actual regex-based solution is a bit more complex. I have amended the answer to reflect it.

Comment: NICE trick using `sb.replace` to take advantage of the fact that the replacement is always(?) the same length as the original string. Otherwise this wouldn't work. Very nice!

Comment: Unfortunately case switching doesn't preserve string length. See: [Does Java's toLowerCase() preserve original string length?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2357315/44522).

Answer (score 0):

How about this transformation function in "**Java 8**"

```
/**
 * Searches the given pattern in the given src string and applies the txr to the
 * matches
 * 
 * @param src     The string to be converted
 * @param pattern the pattern for which the transformers to be applied.
 * @param txr     The transformers for the mathed patterns.
 * @return The result after applying the transformation.
 */
private static String fromTo(String src, String pattern, Function<String, String> txr) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(src);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int last = 0;

    while (m.find()) {
        sb.append(src.substring(last, m.start()));
        sb.append(txr.apply(m.group(0)));
        last = m.end();
    }
    sb.append(src.substring(last));
    return sb.toString();
}
```