# Reformatting a Java String

Tags: java, replace, string-formatting, camelcasing

I have a string that looks like this:

```
CALDARI_STARSHIP_ENGINEERING
```

and I need to edit it to look like

```
Caldari Starship Engineering
```

Unfortunately it's three in the morning and I cannot for the life of me figure this out. I've always had trouble with replacing stuff in strings so any help would be awesome and would help me understand how to do this in the future.

Comment: in a few minutes polygenelubricants will come along and write some wicked cleaver regexp that I don't understand...

Comment: @aioobe: I'm always more than happy to explain regex whenever my answer is unclear, although of course it helps if people also know the basics.

Comment: Sure. You always provide sufficient links etc for me to understand. What I meant was more like, "soon polygenelubricants will surprise me again with what regexps are capable of" :-)  I just wrote a reg-exp variant of your solution for fun. I believe it's robust against the `isEmpty` check that you have (but it's probably not as efficient as your solution).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this is simple enough:

```
    String text = "CALDARI_STARSHIP_ENGINEERING";
    text = text.replace("_", " ");
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : text.split("\\b")) {
        if (!s.isEmpty()) {
            out.append(s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("[" + out.toString() + "]");
    // prints "[Caldari Starship Engineering]"
```

This `split` on the word boundary anchor.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

---

#### `Matcher` loop solution

If you don't mind using `StringBuffer`, you can also use `Matcher.appendReplacement/Tail` loop like this:

```
    String text = "CALDARI_STARSHIP_ENGINEERING";
    text = text.replace("_", " ");

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\b\\w)\\w+").matcher(text);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().toLowerCase());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println("[" + sb.toString() + "]");
    // prints "[Caldari Starship Engineering]"
```

The regex uses assertion to match the "tail" part of a word, the portion that needs to be lowercased. It looks behind `(?<=...)` to see that there's a word boundary `\b` followed by a word character `\w`. Any remaining `\w+` would then need to be matched so it can be lowercased.

#### Related questions

- [Use Java and RegEx to convert casing in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770967/use-java-and-regex-to-convert-casing-in-a-string/)

  - Java regex does not support Perl preprocessing operations `\l` `\u`, `\L`, and `\U`.
- [Java split is eating my characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters/)

  - More examples of using assertions
- [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

  - Unfortunately, `appendReplacement/Tail` only takes `StringBuffer`

Comment: +1 Easy, understandable solution without using 3rd party stuff.

Comment: I suggest using `StringBuilder` because it is faster. The StringBuffer should replace StringBuilder only when you suppose concurrency issues in a multi-threaded application.

Comment: @Leni: unfortunately `Matcher.appendReplacement/Tail` only accepts `StringBuffer`. If you want to use `StringBuilder`, then you can't use those methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
String originalString = "CALDARI_STARSHIP_ENGINEERING";
String newString =
    WordUtils.capitalize(originalString.replace('_', ' ').toLowerCase());
```

`WordUtils` are part of the Commons Lang libraries (http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

Comment: @In silico - you are assuming `WordUtils` are available and can be used.

Comment: So where does WordUtils come from?

Comment: Apache Commons Lang. `org.apache.commons.lang`

Comment: Edited it to mention that it comes from the Commons Lang libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Using reg-exps:

```
String s = "CALDARI_STARSHIP_ENGINEERING";
StringBuilder camel = new StringBuilder();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^_])([^_]*)").matcher(s);
while (m.find())
    camel.append(m.group(1)).append(m.group(2).toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but thats how I implemented the same some time ago:

```
s = "CALDARI_STARSHIP_ENGINEERING";
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
boolean upper = true;
for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if( upper ) {
        b.append(c);
        upper = false;
    } else if( c = '_' ) {
        b.append(" ");
        upper = true;
    } else {
        b.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
    }
}
s = b.toString();
```

Please note that the EVE license agreements might forbit writing external tools that help you in your careers. And it might be the trigger for you to learn Python, because most of EVE is written in Python :).

Comment: Yep - if you change else if( c = '_' )  this is fine

Comment: Daniel, there's EveMon, gtkEveMon, EFT, and the fact that CCP provides both a database dump and an API for this.

Comment: Oh. I assume you can't play Eve anymore without your own Trade monitoring system, Guild tracking system and the like? :)

Comment: Nah, there's ISK to be made. Just nice to be able to instantly check what can make the highest profits... and a neat programming project to boot!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way:

Lower case all

```
   line.toLowerCase();
```

Split into words:

```
   String[] words = line.split("_");
```

Then loop through words capitalising first letter:

```
  words[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
```

Comment: Need to lower case all first and then capitalise first letter