# Is there a regex replacement term for the uppercase/lowercase version of a back reference?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, uppercase

Suppose I want to change a lowercase string to "title case"; where the first letter of every word is capitalized. Can this be done using a single call to `replaceAll()` by using a modifier in the replacement expression?

For example,

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\b(\\S)", "???$1");
```

Where "???" is some expression that folds the case of the next letter.

I have seen this is other tools (like textpad), where `\U` will fold the next letter to uppercase.

?

Comment: This isn't available in Java unfortunately. You will have to run a loop and replace the matches one by one. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2770977/1343161).

Comment: If you're not averse to using Apache Commons, then you can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` like so: `StringUtils.capitalize(str.toLowerCase())`. This can not be done with standard Java libraries however.

Comment: Maybe look at [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html).

Comment: Maybe you could just use a [callback of your own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375420/java-equivalent-to-phps-preg-replace-callback) ?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with replaceAll. But you can use regex and split:

```
public String titleTextConversion(String text) {
    String[] words = text.split("(?<=\\W)|(?=\\W)");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() > 0)
            sb.append(word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()).append(word.substring(1).toLowerCase());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```