# ReplaceAll in Java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'm using [`WordsUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) to `capitalize` words.

Since I can't define which words should be capitalized, I have to make another implementation after capitalize function to put  some words lowercase.

The words that should be lowercase are: `["da, de, di, do, du, das, des, dis, dos, dus"]`.

So, my `code` at the moment is:

```
public static String capitalize(String word) {
   String newWord = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(word);
   newWord = newWord.replaceAll("\\b([d|D][a-zA-Z]{1,2})\\b", "$1").toLowerCase();
   return newWord;
}
```

- Example of inputs:

  1. josé dAs sIlVa
  2. Jorge De PAuLa
  3. MaRiA DAS PauLas

The problem is that the replaceAll is puttng every word lowercase ,  not only the prepositions that matches the `Pattern`.

Comment: That's exactly what `.toLowerCase()` does.  You need to manipulate each match.

Comment: Since you want to check the match per word, consider to split the string and checking the match per word instead of the whole string at once.

Comment: @SLaks, of course I know what `.toLowerCase()` does, but I want to lowerCase only word that matches the `Regex`.

Comment: Then you apparently don't know how expressions work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Java and RegEx to convert casing in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770967/use-java-and-regex-to-convert-casing-in-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java8 solution without third party libs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "hello mY dEAr friends";
    Set<String> ban = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("my", "dear"));
    String result = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s"))
                          .map(s -> capitalize(s, ban))
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(result);
}

static String capitalize(String s, Set<String> ban) {
    String lc = s.toLowerCase();
    return ban.contains(lc) ? lc 
                            : Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tested the first input and it returns me wrong result: "José DAs SIlVa", it should be "José das Silva".

Comment: @developer033 oh, I see, you need to lowercase these words, I'll update the code then

Comment: Now it is working perfectly, you just forgot a thing (toLowerCase) in the end. Instead it won't lowercase the rest of chars in String. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a condition by checking if the word is a target before using the regex and `toLowerCase`

```
List<String> str = Arrays.asList("da, de, di, do, du, das, des, dis, dos, dus".split(", "));
newWord = str.contains(word) ? 
          newWord.replaceAll("\\b([d|D][a-zA-Z]{1,2})\\b", "$1").toLowerCase() : 
          newWord;
```

Answer (score 0):

so you want all the word to be capitalized but the words you specified ?
or you want no word to be capitalized and if the word matches one of specified then you like to convert it to lowercase ?

first case :
you need to take care and determine if you want to lowercase the letters of 
***das***
or any word that contain that word like 
***dasadada***
if only specifically matches the word you specified then

```
Str.matches("firstword|secondword");
```

or if any word that contains those words 
   `Str.matches("(.*)firstword(.*)|(.*)secondword(.*)");`

second case:
then you dont need `String newWord = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(word);`

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the whole String to lower case by doing `newWord.replaceAll("\\b([d|D][a-zA-Z]{1,2})\\b", "$1").toLowerCase();`. You should only convert the matches to lower case.

Below is the code snippet which first converts the input string to upper case and then find & convert each match to the lower case.

Code Snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "josé dAs sIlVa".toUpperCase();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("D(A|E|I|O|U|AS|ES|IS|OS|US)").matcher(str);

    while(m.find()) {
        String match = m.group(0);
        str = str.replace(match,match.toLowerCase());
    }

    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Input:

```
josé dAs sIlVa
```

Output:

```
JOSÉ daS SILVA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

       String[] wordArray = {"jose dAs sIlVa","Jorge De PAuLa","MaRiA DAS PauLas"};
       for(int i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++){
        System.out.println(capitalize(wordArray[i]));   
       }
     }

    static String capitalize(String word) {
             if(word!=null && word!=""){
               String[] wordArray = word.trim().split(" ");
               word= "";
               for(int i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++){
                   String currentWord = wordArray[i].trim();
                   if(currentWord.matches("\\b([d|D][a-zA-Z]{1,2})\\b")){
                       currentWord = currentWord.toLowerCase();
                   }else{
                       currentWord = currentWord.toUpperCase();
                   }
                   word = word+" "+currentWord;
               }
           }
           return word.trim();
        }
}
```

---

Output:

JOSE das SILVA

JORGE de PAULA

MARIA das PAULAS