# Regex replace space and word to toFirstUpper of word

Tags: java, regex, string

I was trying to use regex to change the following string

```
String input = "Creation of book orders"
```

to

```
String output = "CreationOfBookOrders"
```

I tried the following expecting to replace the space and word with word.

```
input.replaceAll("\\s\\w", "(\\w)");
input.replaceAll("\\s\\w", "\\w");
```

but here the string is replacing space and word with character 'w' instead of the word.

I am in a position not to use any `WordUtils` or `StringUtils` or such Util classes. Else I could have replaced all spaces with empty string and applied `WordUtils.capitalize` or similar methods.

How else (preferably using regex) can I get the above `output` from `input`.

Comment: Why are you not in position to use library functions ?

Comment: @noob I am trying to generate code using `xtext` and `xtend`. I am not sure why but I am not able to import any extra jars or dependencies. I am forced to use the basic Java methods configured in them

Comment: In Notepad++ you could search for `\s(\w)` and replace with `\U$1` - not sure if java supports something similar.

Comment: @SebastianProske I tried this in java. `replaceAll("\\s(\\w)","\\U$1")` It is not working there.

Comment: Yep, seems so - have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770967/use-java-and-regex-to-convert-casing-in-a-string), maybe this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with String.replaceAll.  The only modifications that you can make in the replacement string are to interpolate groups matched by the regex.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) for `Matcher.replaceAll` explains how the replacement string is handled.

You will need use a loop.  Here's a simple version:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s\\w");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
int pos = 0;
while (matcher.find(pos)) {
    String replacement = matcher.group().substring(1).toUpperCase();
    pos = matcher.start();
    sb.replace(pos, pos + 2, replacement);
    pos += 1;
}
output = sb.toString();
```

(This could be done more efficiently, but it is complicated.)